# Does denesting work with complex roots and other problems with denesting?

Tags: complex-analysis, radicals, nested-radicals

I've just recently learned about denesting a radical and noted that $\sqrt{a\pm b\sqrt{c}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2c}}2}+\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2c}}2}$, which doesn't seem to be able to hold if $b^2c>a^2$.  It also doesn't seem to hold for complex $a,b,c$.

This also appears to have the affect that $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}=\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}$, creating an obvious problem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264385/does-sqrti-sqrti-sqrti-sqrti-cdots-have-a-closed-form

Comment: 1. You should start well, by "removing the dots", for example, by writing a recursive definition for the continued root (let's call it this way). I.e., $$s_0:=i\text{ and }s_n=\sqrt{i+s_{n-1}},\text{ for }n\geq1.$$ 2. You prove that the sequence $(s_n)_n$ is bounded, and therefore must (by Bolzano-Weierstrass) have a (subsequence) with a limit $s$. 3. You take the limit on both sides of the recursion, use continuity to to obtain $s^2-s-i=0$. 4 Use standard quadratic to solve and find one limit. 5. Using limit's uniqueness you show that the whole sequence converges to $s$.

Comment: @OskarLimka couldn't you have put this in as a question?  Oh, that's what I missed.  Showing that it converges to $s$.  Thank you.

Comment: @Nehorai similar, but I also wonder about the solution to denesting a nested radical in the form $\sqrt{a\pm b\sqrt{c}}$.  Thank you though.

Comment: @SimpleArt In principle you could shorten by showing that the sequence is Cauchy.  Or you could try using a fixed-point theorem for the iteration $s_n = g(s_{n-1})$ where $g(z)=\sqrt{i+z}$. This is a contraction on any disk of radius less than $2$ in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @OskarLimka Could you be more explanatory?  A Cauchy sequence does not prove a sequence convergent, but a convergent series proves it is Cauchy.  Take $\sum\frac1x$.  Cauchy, not convergent.  Never heard of fixed-point theorem, learned about nested radicals 30 minutes ago.

Comment: I never heard of nested radicals for that matter, but in $\mathbb C$ for a sequence to be Cauchy is equivalent for it to be convergent (that's called the Cauchy criterion).  Don't confuse a sequence with its sum (or series).  A fixed-point theorem, such as Banach's contraction principle, gives you a (usually) sufficient condition on a function $g$ for the limit $s$ to exist of a sequence satisfying $s_n=g(s_{n-1})$ for some "good" initial guess $s_0$.

Comment: @OskarLimka Oh.  That truly is interesting.  >_>  Never went in depth into sums or Cauchy sequences.  Thanks.